# New audio interface

Tags: audio-interfaces, pre-amp

I'm looking to get a new interface and was looking at three options:

- Mbox 3
- Apogee Duet w/breakout box
- Apogee Duet 2

I don't have Pro Tools HD so I don't have a need for 192kHz, just 96kHz with quiet preamps with at least 2 XLR inputs and 2 balanced outputs. Does anyone have experience with the first two interfaces?

Price range: $300-600

Comment: Would you be considering an Mbox 3 Pro, or specifically just an Mbox 3 (non-pro)?

Comment: @James Bryant Non-pro. I only need 2 XLR inputs. 

Answer (score 2):

I have the usbpre2 when I head out on he road and it is rock solid. I actually like the headphone amp better than the Apogee Ensemble I own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the new RME Babyface? That looks pretty tasty too!

Also the Sound Devices USBPre2 looks nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

There was a comparison done between the new Mbox3 and the Duet at DUC for what it's worth:

http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=289565

I am assuming you will be using PT9 as your DAW and that you are on a Mac...

As @Andy mentioned, I would also check out RME as their drivers are rock-solid and have decent converters/pres

Answer (score 0):

I have used RME for years.  they are set and forget.  I havent dont any A-B testing to say they are the best, but rock solid.